# I keep getting this message "SyntaxError: Unexpected token" while practicing Codecademy's Do/While section in the JavaScript course

Tags: javascript

```
var y = false
var getToDaChoppa = function() {
    var x = prompt("what kind of dicks do you like?")
    do {
        console.log(x)
    };
    while (y)
};

getToDaChoppa();
```

I need to get it to print out a user-input string once then have it exit the incoming while loop.

I thought linking a variable with a prompt command would store a user's answers, then using a console.log (variable) to print out the stored input answer.

In the end I keep getting the message

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token.

What's causing the syntaxerror?

Comment: Should be `do { body } while(condition);`

Answer (score 2):

You are giving `;` in wrong place

```
do {
    console.log(x)
}; < -- wrong place
while (y)
```

Try like this

```
do {
    console.log(x)
}
while (y);
```

Answer (score 1):

You added the extra ';':

```
var y = false
var getToDaChoppa = function(){
    var x = prompt("what kind of dicks do you like?")
    do {
       console.log(x);
    }
    while(y)
};

getToDaChoppa();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a semicolon after the } on line 5.
The while comes after the bracket.

```
var i = 0;
do {
   i += 1;
   console.log(i);
} while (i < 5);
```